# How to Sum a column as a Double using GRDB

Tags: swift, database, sqlite

I'm trying to convert my app from SQLite.swift to GRDB and I have run into a snag. I need to sum three separate columns and then do some math with the column totals. All three of the columns are stored in the Db as Real numbers which I believe makes them Doubles. The problem I'm having is the three lines of code that are summing the columns are throwing this error. Cannot assign value of type '[Double]' to type 'Double'. Can someone please explain to me what I've done wrong and how to fix it? Thanks in advance for the help.

```
func tallyTheResults() {
    
    let theTable = gTheTable
    
    var thePaidTotal = 0.0
    var theShippingTotal = 0.0
    var theSoldTotal = 0.0
    
    // In the Db, Paid, Shipping and SoldFor are stored as Real numbers
    
    do {
        try Database.shared.databaseConnection!.read { db in
            
    // The three lines below are throwing the error in the editor
    // Cannot assign value of type '[Double]' to type 'Double'
    
            thePaidTotal = try Double.fetchAll(db, sql: "SELECT SUM(Paid) FROM " + theTable)
            
            theShippingTotal = try Double.fetchAll(db, sql: "SELECT SUM(Shipping) FROM " + theTable)
            
            theSoldTotal = try Double.fetchAll(db, sql: "SELECT SUM(SoldFor) FROM " + theTable)
        }
        
    } catch {
        print("Fetching Paid, Shipping and SoldFor columns failed: \(error)")
    }
    
    let theTotal = ((Double(theSoldTotal) - (Double(thePaidTotal)) + Double(theShippingTotal)))
    
    paidSum.text = ModelData.convertDoubleToCurrency(amount: thePaidTotal)
    
    shippingSum.text = ModelData.convertDoubleToCurrency(amount: theShippingTotal)
    
    soldSum.text = ModelData.convertDoubleToCurrency(amount: theSoldTotal)
    
    if theTotal < 0
    {
        totalSum.textColor = .red
    } else {
        totalSum.textColor = .black
    }
    
    totalSum.text = ModelData.convertDoubleToCurrency(amount: theTotal)
}


static func convertDoubleToCurrency(amount: Double) -> String {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    
    return numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: amount))!
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `fetchOne` instead of `fetchAll` when you want one value extracted from one single database row, instead of an array of values extracted from multiple database rows:

```
thePaidTotal = try Double.fetchOne(db, sql: "SELECT SUM(Paid) FROM " + theTable) ?? 0
theShippingTotal = try Double.fetchOne(db, sql: "SELECT SUM(Shipping) FROM " + theTable) ?? 0
theSoldTotal = try Double.fetchOne(db, sql: "SELECT SUM(SoldFor) FROM " + theTable) ?? 0
```

Beware the `SUM` SQLite function would return NULL when the table is empty. `fetchOne` would then return nil. That's why I added `?? 0` at the end of each of each line, in order to turn this NULL into a non-optional 0.0 Double.

For more information, see [Fetching Methods](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/README.md#fetching-methods).

Comment: Thanks. I think I finally understand fetchAll vs fetchOne. fetchAll columns or fetchOne column.